# group an array of object with multiple properties and extract values based on the particular values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i wanted to group by an array of object with multiple field and i have done it and i wanted to concat the email first with respect to the reportName and then with respect to the particular events i have done that part but when i am doing that in the fields i get it undefined with them i want to remove that undefined and print only the strings of email.

```
var data = [ { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abc45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abcd55@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'addfs45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'singh45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'singh45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abcd55@gmail.com',
    event: 'open' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'abc45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'addfs45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abc45@gmail.com',
    event: 'open' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'abc45@gmail.com',
    event: 'open' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'hfhhfg@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'abc45@gmail.com',
    event: 'open' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abcd55@gmail.com',
    event: 'open' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'singh45@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'abcd55@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abc45@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'abcd55@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abcd55@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'abc45@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hfhhfg@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'singh45@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'addfs45@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'hfhhfg@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hfhhfg@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'addfs45@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'def',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'jjj@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'def',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'jjj@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'def',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'def',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'def',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'singh45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'def',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'jjj@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'def',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'def',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'def',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'jjj@gmail.com',
    event: 'open' },
  { office: 'def',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'singh45@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'hfghf@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'singh45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'ghthh@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com',
    event: 'open' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'hdgdfhf333@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'hdgshgfhg@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'hhhhhhrt45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'hdghdghhh@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com',
    event: 'open' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'jjhhh@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'hdhdhcgsfhgf@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hfghf@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'vipin@indinnovation.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',
    event: 'open' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hdhdhcgsfhgf@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hdgshgfhg@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'ghthh@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hfghf@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hhhhhhrt45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'ghthh@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'singh45@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'vipin@indinnovation.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hdgdfhf333@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hdghdghhh@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'jjhhh@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'jjhhh@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hdgshgfhg@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hhhhhhrt45@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hdgdfhf333@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hdhdhcgsfhgf@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hdghdghhh@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'vipin@indinnovation.com',
    event: 'open' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: 'singh45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'hhhfgfg',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'anami@thotslab.com',
    event: 'open' },
  { office: 'hhhfgfg',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'hhhfgfg',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'hhhfgfg',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'hhhfgfg',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'singh45@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },
  { office: 'hhhfgfg',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'singh45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'hhhfgfg',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',
    event: 'delivered' },
  { office: 'hhhfgfg',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: 'hgdfchgf@gmail.com',
    event: 'processed' },

 ]
```

i have tried to solve this problem using this way

```
const processArray = data.filter(itms => {
      return itms.event == 'processed';
    });
    const openEvent = data.filter(itms => {
      return itms.event == 'open';
    });
    const recieved = data.filter(itms => {
      return itms.event == 'delivered';
    });
    //console.log(processArray)
    const processEmailRecord = processArray.map(arrayofObj => ({
      processEmail: arrayofObj.email,
      office: arrayofObj.office,
      reportName: arrayofObj.reportName,
    }));

    const openEmailRecord = openEvent.map(arrayofObj => ({
      openEmail: arrayofObj.email,
      office: arrayofObj.office,
      reportName: arrayofObj.reportName,
    }));

    const recEmailRecord = recieved.map(arrayofObj => ({
      recEmail: arrayofObj.email,
      office: arrayofObj.office,
      reportName: arrayofObj.reportName,
    }));


const eventwiseArray = [...processEmailRecord, ...recEmailRecord, ...openEmailRecord];


    let hash1 = Object.create(null);
    let eventArray = [];
    eventwiseArray.forEach(o => {
      var key = ['office', 'reportName']
        .map(function(k) {
          return o[k];
        })
        .join('|');

      if (!hash1[key]) {
        hash1[key] = {office: o.office, reportName: o.reportName,email:' ',processEmail:'',recEmail:'',openEmail:''};
        eventArray.push(hash1[key]);
      }
      ['email'].forEach(k => {
        if (hash1[key] && !hash1[key][k].includes(o[k])) {
          hash1[key][k] += o[k] + ',';
        }
      });
     ['processEmail'].forEach(k => {
        if (hash1[key] && !hash1[key][k].includes(o[k])) {
          hash1[key][k] += o[k] + ',';
        }
      });
      ['recEmail'].forEach(k => {
        if (hash1[key] && !hash1[key][k].includes(o[k])) {
          hash1[key][k] += o[k] + ',';
        }
      });
      ['openEmail'].forEach(k => {
        if (hash1[key] && !hash1[key][k].includes(o[k])) {
          hash1[key][k] += o[k] + ',';
        }
      });


    });
```

i am getting output in this way

```
[ { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: ' undefined,xyz@gmail.com,ggrr@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,abc45@gmail.com,addfs45@gmail.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,hfhhfg@gmail.com,abcd55@gmail.com,',
    processEmail: 'ggrr@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,abcd55@gmail.com,abc45@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,hfhhfg@gmail.com,addfs45@gmail.com,undefined,',
    recEmail: 'undefined,xyz@gmail.com,ggrr@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,abc45@gmail.com,addfs45@gmail.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,hfhhfg@gmail.com,abcd55@gmail.com,',
    openEmail: 'undefined,abc45@gmail.com,' },
  { office: 'abc',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: ' undefined,abc45@gmail.com,abcd55@gmail.com,addfs45@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,ggrr@gmail.com,hfhhfg@gmail.com,',
    processEmail: 'ggrr@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,abc45@gmail.com,abcd55@gmail.com,hfhhfg@gmail.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,addfs45@gmail.com,undefined,',
    recEmail: 'undefined,abc45@gmail.com,abcd55@gmail.com,addfs45@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,ggrr@gmail.com,hfhhfg@gmail.com,',
    openEmail: 'undefined,abcd55@gmail.com,abc45@gmail.com,' },
  { office: 'def',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: ' undefined,jjj@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,',
    processEmail: 'jjj@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,undefined,',
    recEmail: 'undefined,jjj@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,',
    openEmail: 'undefined,' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: ' undefined,singh45@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,hfgjg@gmail.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,jjhhh@gmail.com,ggrr@gmail.com,hfghf@gmail.com,vipin@indinnovation.com,hdhdhcgsfhgf@gmail.com,hdgshgfhg@gmail.com,ghthh@gmail.com,hhhhhhrt45@gmail.com,hdgdfhf333@gmail.com,hdghdghhh@gmail.com,',
    processEmail: 'jjhhh@gmail.com,ggrr@gmail.com,hfghf@gmail.com,vipin@indinnovation.com,hdhdhcgsfhgf@gmail.com,hdgshgfhg@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,ghthh@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,hdgdfhf333@gmail.com,hfgjg@gmail.com,hhhhhhrt45@gmail.com,hdghdghhh@gmail.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,undefined,',
    recEmail: 'undefined,singh45@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,ghthh@gmail.com,hfghf@gmail.com,hhhhhhrt45@gmail.com,hfgjg@gmail.com,vipin@indinnovation.com,hdghdghhh@gmail.com,jjhhh@gmail.com,hdgshgfhg@gmail.com,hdgdfhf333@gmail.com,hdhdhcgsfhgf@gmail.com,ggrr@gmail.com,',
    openEmail: 'undefined,hfgjg@gmail.com,vipin@indinnovation.com,' },
  { office: 'hhhfgfg',
    reportName: 'footprints',
    email: ' undefined,anami@thotslab.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,hgdfchgf@gmail.com,',
    processEmail: 'abcdg45@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,hgdfchgf@gmail.com,undefined,',
    recEmail: 'undefined,xyz@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,',
    openEmail: 'undefined,anami@thotslab.com,' },
  { office: 'def',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: ' undefined,abcdg45@gmail.com,jjj@gmail.com,',
    processEmail: 'undefined,',
    recEmail: 'abcdg45@gmail.com,jjj@gmail.com,undefined,',
    openEmail: 'undefined,jjj@gmail.com,' },
  { office: 'ghi',
    reportName: 'payroll',
    email: ' undefined,hfghf@gmail.com,ghthh@gmail.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,hdgdfhf333@gmail.com,hdgshgfhg@gmail.com,hhhhhhrt45@gmail.com,hdghdghhh@gmail.com,hfgjg@gmail.com,hdhdhcgsfhgf@gmail.com,ggrr@gmail.com,jjhhh@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,',
    processEmail: 'undefined,',
    recEmail: 'hfghf@gmail.com,ghthh@gmail.com,abcdg45@gmail.com,hdgdfhf333@gmail.com,hdgshgfhg@gmail.com,hhhhhhrt45@gmail.com,hdghdghhh@gmail.com,hdhdhcgsfhgf@gmail.com,hfgjg@gmail.com,ggrr@gmail.com,jjhhh@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,singh45@gmail.com,undefined,',
    openEmail: 'undefined,hfgjg@gmail.com,ggrr@gmail.com,' } ]
```

but i wanted to get the output without undefined written in front of it.all the emails in it must be unique like my solution's output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the mails and add the values to the distinct groups by taking a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for getting unique emails.

```js
var data = [{ office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abc45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abcd55@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'addfs45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'singh45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'xyz@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'ggrr@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'ggrr@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'singh45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abcd55@gmail.com', event: 'open' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'abc45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'addfs45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abc45@gmail.com', event: 'open' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'ggrr@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'abc45@gmail.com', event: 'open' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'hfhhfg@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'abc45@gmail.com', event: 'open' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'ggrr@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abcd55@gmail.com', event: 'open' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'singh45@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'abcd55@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abc45@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'xyz@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'abcd55@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abcd55@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'abc45@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hfhhfg@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'singh45@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'addfs45@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'hfhhfg@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hfhhfg@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'abc', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'addfs45@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'def', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'jjj@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'def', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'jjj@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'def', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'xyz@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'def', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'def', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'singh45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'def', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'jjj@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'def', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'def', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'def', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'jjj@gmail.com', event: 'open' }, { office: 'def', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'singh45@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'hfghf@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'singh45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'xyz@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'ghthh@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com', event: 'open' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'hdgdfhf333@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'hdgshgfhg@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'hhhhhhrt45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'hdghdghhh@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com', event: 'open' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'jjhhh@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'hdhdhcgsfhgf@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'ggrr@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hfghf@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'vipin@indinnovation.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'ggrr@gmail.com', event: 'open' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hdhdhcgsfhgf@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hdgshgfhg@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'ghthh@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'xyz@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hfghf@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'ggrr@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hhhhhhrt45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'ghthh@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'singh45@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'vipin@indinnovation.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hdgdfhf333@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hdghdghhh@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'jjhhh@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'jjhhh@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hdgshgfhg@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hhhhhhrt45@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hdgdfhf333@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'xyz@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hdhdhcgsfhgf@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hdghdghhh@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'vipin@indinnovation.com', event: 'open' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'ggrr@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'ghi', reportName: 'payroll', email: 'singh45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'hhhfgfg', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'anami@thotslab.com', event: 'open' }, { office: 'hhhfgfg', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'hhhfgfg', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'xyz@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'hhhfgfg', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'xyz@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'hhhfgfg', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'singh45@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }, { office: 'hhhfgfg', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'singh45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'hhhfgfg', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com', event: 'delivered' }, { office: 'hhhfgfg', reportName: 'footprints', email: 'hgdfchgf@gmail.com', event: 'processed' }],
    result = Object
        .values(data.reduce((r, { office, reportName, event, email }) => {
            var key = [office, reportName].join('|'),
                name = { processed: 'processEmail', delivered: 'recEmail', open: 'openEmail' }[event];

            r[key] = r[key] || { office, reportName, email: new Set };
            r[key].email.add(email);
            if (!r[key][name]) r[key][name] = new Set;
            r[key][name].add(email);
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(o => {
            ['email', 'processEmail', 'recEmail', 'openEmail'].forEach(k => {
                if (k in o) o[k] = [...o[k]].join();
            });
            return o;
        });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: in this it work fine but i needed all the email occurs one time not multiple times in the email email id is repeating 2 times and if possible make it possible for other emails also because i don't know how to use includes in it .in my above solution i have used includes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made this more complicated then it has to be, my approach will be something like this:

```js
var data = [ { office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abc45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abcd55@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'addfs45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'singh45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'xyz@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'singh45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abcd55@gmail.com',event: 'open' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'abc45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'addfs45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abc45@gmail.com',event: 'open' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'abc45@gmail.com',event: 'open' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'hfhhfg@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'abc45@gmail.com',event: 'open' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abcd55@gmail.com',event: 'open' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'singh45@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'abcd55@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abc45@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'xyz@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'abcd55@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abcd55@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'abc45@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hfhhfg@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'singh45@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'addfs45@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'hfhhfg@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hfhhfg@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'abc',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'addfs45@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'def',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'jjj@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'def',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'jjj@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'def',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'xyz@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'def',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'def',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'singh45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'def',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'jjj@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'def',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'def',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'def',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'jjj@gmail.com',event: 'open' },{ office: 'def',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'singh45@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'hfghf@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'singh45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'xyz@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'ghthh@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com',event: 'open' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'hdgdfhf333@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'hdgshgfhg@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'hhhhhhrt45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'hdghdghhh@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com',event: 'open' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'jjhhh@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'hdhdhcgsfhgf@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hfghf@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'vipin@indinnovation.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',event: 'open' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hdhdhcgsfhgf@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hdgshgfhg@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'ghthh@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'xyz@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hfghf@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hhhhhhrt45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'ghthh@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'singh45@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'vipin@indinnovation.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hdgdfhf333@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hdghdghhh@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'jjhhh@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'jjhhh@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hfgjg@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hdgshgfhg@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hhhhhhrt45@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hdgdfhf333@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'xyz@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hdhdhcgsfhgf@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hdghdghhh@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'vipin@indinnovation.com',event: 'open' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'ggrr@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'ghi',reportName: 'payroll',email: 'singh45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'hhhfgfg',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'anami@thotslab.com',event: 'open' },{ office: 'hhhfgfg',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'hhhfgfg',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'xyz@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'hhhfgfg',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'xyz@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'hhhfgfg',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'singh45@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },{ office: 'hhhfgfg',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'singh45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'hhhfgfg',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'abcdg45@gmail.com',event: 'delivered' },{ office: 'hhhfgfg',reportName: 'footprints',email: 'hgdfchgf@gmail.com',event: 'processed' },];


const result = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  let o = a.find(v => (v.office === c.office && v.reportName === c.reportName));
  if (!o) {
    o = {
      office: c.office,
      reportName: c.reportName,
      email: new Set(),
      recEmail: new Set(),
      processEmail: new Set(),
      openEmail: new Set()
    };
    a.push(o);
  }
  
  o.email.add(c.email);
  
  switch(c.event) {
    case 'processed':
      o.processEmail.add(c.email);
      break;
    case 'delivered':
      o.recEmail.add(c.email);
      break;
    case 'open':
      o.openEmail.add(c.email);
      break;
  }
  return a;
}, [])
.map((v) => ({
  ...v,
  email: [...v.email].join(),
  processEmail: [...v.processEmail].join(),
  recEmail: [...v.recEmail].join(),
  openEmail: [...v.openEmail].join()
}));

console.log(result);
```

What this does is to first check (the `a.find(..)` call) if there was already an object created for the `office` and `reportName` of the object at the current iteration (`c`). If it wasn't, one is created and added to the result array and then, the `switch` statement adds the email to the appropriate property of the found/created object.

This approach is not that efficient because of the `.find` call at each iteration, it can be improved by using a `Map` or `object` which has as keys `c.office + c.reportName`.

Comment: how can i concat all the emails like for email like this ['abc45@gmail.com,abcd55@gmail.com'] and same for the other processEmail and others

Comment: @amarjeetsingh I've edited my answer to include that.

Comment: in this it work fine but i needed all the email occurs one time not multiple times in the email id is repeating 2 times and if possible make it possible for other emails also because i don't know how to use includes in it .in my above solution i have used includes.

Comment: @amarjeetsingh I've edited my answer to use `Set`s instead of `Array`s to prevent duplicates.